# In C, why can I not cast pow(2,64) to an unsigned long?

Tags: c, casting, limit

I'm trying to print the maximum value for an unsigned long in C (18446744073709551615 on my machine) without using values from limits.h and without bitwise operators (exercise 2-1 from K&R, using only information that has been mentioned in the book up to then). Obviously just as an exercise, not for any real world application.
My idea (which worked for all other data types) was

```
printf("Unsigned long: Max: %lu\n", (unsigned long)(pow(2,sizeof(unsigned long)*8)-1));
```

But for some reason, casting the output of (pow(2,64)-1) to an unsigned long is displayed as 2^63, even though unsigned long is big enough to show pow(2,64)-1

I have tried

```
printf("Unsigned long: Max: %lu\n", ULONG_MAX); // works
printf("Unsigned long: Max: %lu\n", 2*(unsigned long)pow(2,63)-1); // works
printf("Unsigned long: Max: %.0f\n", pow(2,64)-1); // sort of works, but displays 18446744073709551616, i.e., 2^64 instead of 2^64-1
printf("Unsigned long: Max: %lu\n", (unsigned long)(pow(2,sizeof(unsigned long)*8)-1)); // does not work
printf("Unsigned long: Max: %lu\n", (unsigned long)pow(2,64)-1); //does not work
```

I don't understand why the last 2 options do not work.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Because it can only return a `double`? https://linux.die.net/man/3/pow

Comment: `pow` return a `double` and not all 64 bit integers can be exactly represented by it.

Comment: "displayed as 2^63" -- I don't think so, what is the exact output? What would you expect? Point is, this makes your question less clear. Anyhow, what size is your `long double`? The come as 32 bit and 64 bit, I expect the latter. For that, it's just as large as a `double`. Since the double has a wider range, it can't have the same number of significant digits. Try to find an explanation of how floating point numbers work, it will make sense then.

Comment: Thanks. But why does it work up to 2^63 (19 digits) and not for 2^64 (20 digits)? I though a double can only store 15 decimal places, shouldn't it stop working for lower values? And why does it simply display 2^63 when I want it to print 2^64? Shouldn't it just display the first couple of digits of 2^64 and the last digits would be wrong? Sorry for these basic questions, I'm not that firm on how doubles are stored

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt thanks for the reply. 
printf("Unsigned long: Max: %lu\n", (unsigned long)(pow(2,sizeof(unsigned long)*8)-1)); displays 9223372036854775808 on my system. I would expect 18446744073709551615. Size of long double is 64bit on my system ,double is 32, long and unsigned long also 32bit.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to clarify that, which is better than in comments.

Comment: "I'm trying to print the maximum value for an unsigned long in C (18446744073709551615 on my machine) without using values from limits.h"  Forget about floating point and just print `~0UL`. Unless you could that as a bitwise operator, I guess...

Comment: @Ben253 It does not seem right that unsigned long is 32 bits on your system - did you mean 64 bits? Can you confirm that double is 32 bits?

Comment: Just use `(unsigned long)-1`.

Comment: Quote: "... casting the output of (pow(2,64)-1) to an unsigned long is displayed as 2^63..." Really? Please post your exact output. Which system/compiler?

Comment: @nielsen `int` <= `long` <= `long long`. It's a useless type unless `int` is 16 bits and `long long` is 64 bits. If you want 64 bits then use `long long` or `int64_t`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, I am asking because of the comment above by Ben253 stating the unsigned long is 32 bits, but that does not match with the question.

Comment: "using only information that has been mentioned in the book up to then" You can't use `pow` then, because `<math.h>` has not been mentioned. And you should *never* use `pow` when computing an integer anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems here. The expression `pow(2,64)` can be represented exactly in a double, but when you typecast it with `(unsigned long)pow(2, 64)`, you are effectively attempting to do the same thing as the expression `1 << 64`. This number requires at least 65 bits to represent it. But, by the look of it, the `unsigned long` type on your system is only 64 bits long.

It is true that the result of the expression `(1 << 64) - 1` can be represented in only 64 bits, but it's too late - you have used an intermediate expression that is not representable along the way.

Your other attempt, which is to use `(unsigned long)(pow(2, 64) - 1)` fails for a different reason. Although `pow(2, 64)` can be represented exactly in a `double`, `pow(2, 64) - 1` cannot. This is because a double has only 53 bits of mantissa. Once again, this means that the result when cast to `(unsigned long)` is guaranteed to be wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had suspected something along those lines, but wasn't quite sure about the details, your answer clarified it

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Undefined behavior.

Assuming `unsigned long` is 64 bit, this code

```
(unsigned long)pow(2,64)
```

has undefined behavior. The reason is that the integral part of the floating point number can't be represented in an `unsigned long`. For such situations the C standard specifies that the behavior is undefined.

This code

```
(unsigned long)(pow(2,sizeof(unsigned long)*8)-1))
```

which is the same as

```
(unsigned long)(pow(2,64)-1))
```

when `unsigned long` is 64 bit, is a bit more tricky.

It may have undefined behavior, it may have well-defined behavior.

It depends on the precision used when doing the floating point calculation of `(pow(2,64)-1))`. The C standard doesn't specify precision for floating point types so it's system dependent whether the math result can be represented in a floating number. If not, the floating point rounding mode being used may be important in this case.

Comment: This is IMO the correct answer. It is very likely that converting pow(2,64)-1 is undefined behavior. Unless the double type is strictly more than 64 bits, then it will not have precision to represent 2^64-1 exactly. Thus the subtraction of 1 will probably not change the value and thus pow(2,64)-1 will be equal to pow(2,64)

Comment: @nielsen It's also worth to remember that the compiler doesn't need to (probably wont) produce code that actually calls `pow`.  At least with optimization on, it's very likely that the "calculation" is done at compile time so that `pow` is never called at runtime. Here https://godbolt.org/z/acY18G9Td it seems gcc simply decides to turn it into code something like `(unsigned long) -1` and `(unsigned long) -2`.